# 2012 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest

Tags: discussion, election

The following is a "digest" version of the [2012 Moderator Election Town Hall Chat](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-monday-9pm-edt-tuesday-1am-utc). The format, [as described on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests), is one *answer* to this question *for every question* asked in the Town Hall, containing all the candidate's answers to that question.

**To view the digest chronologically, please sort the answers by "oldest"**.

If you have questions or comments about this, **please do not answer this question** as the answers are designed to be used for the questions from the Town hall itself. Instead, please ask on [the parent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests) or in [the Town Hall Discussion Room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/352/town-hall-discussion).

If you see any corrections which need to be made to this digest, or if you were a candidate who was unable to attend the town hall and would like your answers included, please @Rebecca or @TimStone [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/556/math-town-hall-chat) and let us know!

Comment: Note that not every single message is captured in this digest, since I had some difficulty reconciling all of the extended conversation threads with the format of the digest. Please [see the chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511715#4511715) for the unabridged conversation. If I omitted anything directly related to what's been posted here, let me know which messages are missing and I'll gladly amend the digest.

Comment: Thanks for the work, Tim! Sorry I had to miss the event due to Time-Zone.

Comment: @TimStone Is it possible to contact the candidates that have not answered the questions and ask them to?

Comment: @Phira I'll ask Rebecca about the possibility of reminding the remaining candidates that they can still answer. If they do provide  answers, I'll be sure to pull their responses into the digest.

Comment: Well done @TimStone, doesn't seem easy at all to put all those messages together like this. Thank you.

Comment: @Willie: I guess my suggestion to fly current moderators and candidates to a live chat in Dubai didn't work.

Comment: @Asaf or we can go the route of the US Republican nomination process and schedule 12 more debates.

Answer (score 8):

### *[image: MaoYiyi] [MaoYiyi](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/31214/maoyiyi) [suggested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512158#4512158):* I would like to see something to protect a new user, that asked a poor question the first time.  Not everyone that is going to come to MSE is going to be a college student with knowledge of how to ask a proper question.  IE.  they ask a question and it gets harshly downvoted and now they don't have the points to do anything.

---

**[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512165#4512165):**  That is true. We need to create a welcoming policy.

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513450#4513450):**  I think the way we treat them now is not that problematic. I thought about having a public comment to welcome them and warn them about FAQ rules and such things since I have seen posting that comment might to lead to some serious problems. But what I've seen was to post that comment and editing their questions to an acceptable form afterwards.

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513486#4513486):** But we need to be careful, welcoming a new user shouldn't condone wrong behaviors. As it is, questions are being asked in a format which the whole community agree about, every new user needs to learn it. We should be careful about the quality of the site more than a user who comes, asks some questions and vanishes into the thin air.

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [concluded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513490#4513490):** I was always against the behaviors and thought which might make the site look like a forum, there's a huge difference between normal forums on the internet and a Q&A site.

Answer (score 5):

### *[image: Alex Becker] [Alex Becker](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/10440/alex-becker) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512198#4512198):* I think the key to attracting experts is to have good questions. How would the candidates go about promoting good questions?

---

**[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512239#4512239):**  This is a very good question. And I don't think it's at all easy to answer. I tend to read and upvote the questions that pique my interest, as I hope that most users do. There is an unfortunate problem here that more basic questions and answers sometimes get more votes simply because more people understand them. I don't know a good response to this problem, but I admit that it exists.

**[image: Bill Dubuque] [Bill Dubuque](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/197/bill-dubuque) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512259#4512259):**  One possibility is to attempt to rally the community to crowdsource improvement of poor questions ,so that there are many good examples to be seen. If all of the front-page questions are well-motivated, then its likely that new users will follow the model.

- **[image: MaoYiyi] [MaoYiyi](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/31214/maoyiyi) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512268#4512268):**  Like a style sheet, of good/bad questions?

  **[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512274#4512274):**  Not really. We edit poor quality questions. Polish them so they look neat and shiny.

  - **[image: MaoYiyi] [MaoYiyi](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/31214/maoyiyi) [remarked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512292#4512292):**  Yes,  that does help, but it might be good to have an example they can check beforehand so you don't have so much work to do.

    **[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512314#4512314):**  That is interesting. You can always choose the "votes" tab to get upvoted and downvoted answers. Maybe an interactive guide/tutorial/walkthrough will serve well.

  **[image: Bill Dubuque] [Bill Dubuque](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/197/bill-dubuque) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512291#4512291):**  The goal would be to attempt to keep the  front page of questions to always be model examples. We have enough users to do that, if everyone helped a little. New users rarely read the FAQ, but they probably browse the front page.

**[image: robjohn] [robjohn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512294#4512294):**  promoting good questions and discouraging poor questions are both nice goals. Improving poor questions and deleting poor questions are things that anyone can do.  As a moderator, I don't know if there is anything more one can do.

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513509#4513509):**  By upvoting them, posting them on personal stuff like G+ or FB if any, and bringing them up in a place like our chat room. But everything does not go as well as we expect.

Answer (score 5):

### *[image: Isaac] [Isaac](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/220/isaac) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512283#4512283):* In every math.SE election so far, the highest-rep users have been the winners.  Is this a good thing?  Is it a result of users voting based solely on rep?

---

**[image: chessmath] [chessmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32609/chessmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512325#4512325):**  User with hight rep are generally experts and helpful people. But it is not all

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4514030#4514030):**  I'd admit the more rep a user has earned, the more the community trust him/her. (there are exceptions to every rule). But it's not all about rep. In my case, I once registered, took a look and left the site as I wasn't motivated enough. It's about a month that I am active here since I got accepted to my fav-institute and I know I'll study mathematics, not computer science.

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4514032#4514032):** That saying, I've earned about half of my rep during the last week, plus some important badges.

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [concluded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4514033#4514033):** Also, I've seen many low-rep users being moderator on different SE sites.

Answer (score 3):

### *[image: Eric Gregor] [Eric Gregor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/33561/eric-gregor) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511903#4511903):* Are there any issues on which the candidates feel they would like to change the status quo? To what extent do you consider yourselves "progressives"?

---

**[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511923#4511923):**  With respect to 'changing the status quo,' I do not believe that moderators have any special say in that respect. The SE model is that of self-governance, and in the [Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) there is a nice line: "Moderators are human exception handlers." In other words, I will be no more proactive than I was before, and I think that all users should feel that they have a role in the future of the community.

- **[image: Eric Gregor] [Eric Gregor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/33561/eric-gregor) [clarified](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511926#4511926):**  I didn't necessarily mean "as moderator." I'm asking about how you want MSE to evolve or not, etc.

  **[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511955#4511955):**  That's very true. I'm sorry. I would say that I am not particularly 'progressive.' I like how the site currently runs, and I like how the community seems willing to participate on meta to address concerns. But if I were to do one thing, it would be to encourage more people to think they have a role in the community. Many decisions here are guided by the same 10-12 people here.

  **[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [agreed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511988#4511988):**  That is rather my thought on the meta participation. We need more people participating. I think **I** have to participate more.

  - **[image: chessmath] [chessmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32609/chessmath) [remarked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512010#4512010):**  The problem is that the system doesn't help participate in meta. Mainly because of the downvotes in polemic opinions !

    **[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512024#4512024):**  Well, that is one issue. People tend to down vote before discussing.

    **[image: chessmath] [chessmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32609/chessmath) [concluded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512034#4512034):** I think we should have somewhere specific to discuss theses questions without voting or downvoting or upvoting.

  **[image: Bill Dubuque] [Bill Dubuque](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/197/bill-dubuque) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511998#4511998) to [Eric Gregor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/33561/eric-gregor):**  You've touched on a key point: evolution. In some sense we are stagnant now as far as attracting further experts. The site needs a healthy balance of students and teachers. We need more teachers. To attract them we will need to eliminate some of the friction over the contentious issues. It can be done, but it will require careful thought.

**[image: Bill Dubuque] [Bill Dubuque](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/197/bill-dubuque) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511946#4511946) with reference to [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath)’s [response](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511923#4511923):**  In fact, I think we should encourage users to play a greater role by participating more in meta. Often times it is difficult to infer what the consensus is on matters because too few folks participate on meta.

**[image: robjohn] [robjohn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511935#4511935):**  I think that math.SE is very nice as it stands. However, I am always open to listen to ways to improve. If something seems like a  good idea, I will promote it to the other mods.

**[image: robjohn] [robjohn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511982#4511982):**  One thing I would like to see is better support of MathJax.

**[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511949#4511949):**  I will participate in new proposals and ideas more actively as a moderator. However, I have proposed new ideas which haven't been really welcomed by the community. I think one should not force a change, but let it happen softly.

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513245#4513245):**  Not on any special issues off top the of my head, but I need to discuss some special things with the other moderators, e.g. when to delete a question or an answer. And as I said, bringing up some special issues to meta seems necessary to me.

Answer (score 2):

### *[Alex Becker http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d8f3b5ea4cc07f2bca5e7594a79024ed?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d8f3b5ea4cc07f2bca5e7594a79024ed?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Alex Becker](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/10440/alex-becker) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511741#4511741):* Candidates: Do you believe that promoting math.SE is part of a moderator's duty? If so, how would you go about doing so?

---

**[Peter Tamaroff http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511750#4511750):** I don't believe it is a mods duty, but if one feels the site is useful and one can do something to improve it and raise more awareness of its great uses, then one should do so.

**[Peter Tamaroff http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511756#4511756):** Any normal user that is slightly passionate about MSE should do so.

**[mixedmath http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1066fe6e02bf9b9a52aef4c9b3f8457d?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1066fe6e02bf9b9a52aef4c9b3f8457d?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511794#4511794):**  Do I believe that promoting MSE is a part of a moderator's duties? I think that's an interesting question. Whether or not it is a *responsibility* of a moderator (of which I'm uncertain), I think that in general we should all try to bring people here. I think that most who know me (in real life) know that I promote MSE, and I bring it up on my blog from time to time.

**[chessmath http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8d4b364f032ec5fb17c157bd5df47247?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8d4b364f032ec5fb17c157bd5df47247?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [chessmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32609/chessmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511754#4511754):** Promoting the site is duty of everybody who likes the site! And it is been done well we have  high quality member here!

**[Bill Dubuque http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/860a1d8e8626a30e511098b703b61ea8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/860a1d8e8626a30e511098b703b61ea8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Bill Dubuque](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/197/bill-dubuque) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511887#4511887):**  I have rallied many folks from sci.math to join MSE. I think it is crucial to fill gaps in knowledge here, so that we have at least a handful of experts in all of the major fields of math.

- **[Peter Tamaroff http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [agreed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511890#4511890):**  I agree. But I hope that doesn't discourage [non-experts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/how-can-non-experts-best-contribute) to contribute.

  **[chessmath http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8d4b364f032ec5fb17c157bd5df47247?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8d4b364f032ec5fb17c157bd5df47247?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [chessmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32609/chessmath) [remarked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511894#4511894):**  Experts will come since we have quality and a friendly place.

  **[Bill Dubuque http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/860a1d8e8626a30e511098b703b61ea8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/860a1d8e8626a30e511098b703b61ea8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Bill Dubuque](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/197/bill-dubuque) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511902#4511902):**  I hope so. I do worry though that experts might be scared off by some of the meta level issues if we don't try to handle them more smoothly.

**[robjohn http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6089b0e9c9c12e6fa7ca556f3c860b66?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6089b0e9c9c12e6fa7ca556f3c860b66?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [robjohn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512230#4512230):**  I don't think it is necessarily part of what a moderator is *supposed* to do here, but I think it is good to promote the site where possible. I have pointed several people to the site that I think would benefit from the site or who would benefit the site.

**[Gigili http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cf4d8d67ef2dbe02a528fed9ab5360f8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cf4d8d67ef2dbe02a528fed9ab5360f8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513070#4513070):**  It's not of course a duty. But I've done it before for another SE as a regular user, so no doubt I'll do it when I am a moderator.

Answer (score 2):

### *[Marvis http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/26ccf25f4d50464ee7934932ce91462d?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/26ccf25f4d50464ee7934932ce91462d?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Marvis](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/911/marvis) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511770#4511770):* Will there ever be a consensus on homework? I got a down-vote here ([How do you solve the following trigonometric equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142008/how-do-you-solve-the-following-trigonometric-equation/142013#142013)) for providing the complete answer.

#### I have become indifferent to homework questions since there seems to be no consensus. If the mods agree that posting solutions is allowed, kindly announce this on meta? Similarly, if the mods agree that posting complete solution to homework is not allowed, how will the user providing the full solution be penalized?

---

**[Peter Tamaroff http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511802#4511802):**  If the user asked not to provide a full answer, then the downvote is called for. Otherwise, I believe is under the answerer's criteria wether to provide a full answer or not. One can help with homework in many ways. Maybe some users feel you're trying to get some rep out of the OP by providing it, but I see no harm. I repeat, if the OP was explicit, then I think it is not correct to do so, but it is under each of our criteria to provide a full answer or not.

**[Peter Tamaroff http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511823#4511823):**  The penalization, if it should happen, has to be from the community itself. Just as when one down votes an answer that is not useful, wrong, misleading, confusing or whatever quality standard it is not meeting.

- **[Marvis http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/26ccf25f4d50464ee7934932ce91462d?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/26ccf25f4d50464ee7934932ce91462d?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Marvis](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/911/marvis) [remarked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511829#4511829):**  It really doesn't make sense to me unless there is a firm policy. I can also interpret that the user does not want a hint since the user does not mention anything in the question.

  **[Peter Tamaroff http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511838#4511838):**  Then I think users are free to interpret his needs.

**[Bill Dubuque http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/860a1d8e8626a30e511098b703b61ea8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/860a1d8e8626a30e511098b703b61ea8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Bill Dubuque](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/197/bill-dubuque) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511824#4511824):**  I doubt there will be any consensus on homework. My view on such contentious matters is to try to make both sides aware of all the issues in hope that they will respect each others viewpoints, so that we can avoid friction on the main site.

- **[Antonio Vargas http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b5aa3d659a3423aa583840597a572e24?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b5aa3d659a3423aa583840597a572e24?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Antonio Vargas](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32991/antonio-vargas) [asked for clarification](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511843#4511843):**  How would you go about doing this, specifically?

  **[Peter Tamaroff http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b05ae65885b5668b2dba114419bc0ce8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [suggested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511851#4511851):**  Mariano's approach was quite good. I think that is what Bill is talking about.

  **[Bill Dubuque http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/860a1d8e8626a30e511098b703b61ea8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/860a1d8e8626a30e511098b703b61ea8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Bill Dubuque](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/197/bill-dubuque) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511866#4511866):**  By encouraging folks to join meta discussions on these topics. I think many folks aren't aware of all the complex factors that motivate the various positions held. Seeing such, they might be more respectful of differing viewpoints.

  **[Alex Becker http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d8f3b5ea4cc07f2bca5e7594a79024ed?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d8f3b5ea4cc07f2bca5e7594a79024ed?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Alex Becker](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/10440/alex-becker) [remarked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511882#4511882):**  The problem I see with that is it only addresses the answering side of homework questions. I find it unlikely that many of the users who pose "problematic" (no work shown, imperative, etc.) HW questions will be active on meta at all.

  **[Bill Dubuque http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/860a1d8e8626a30e511098b703b61ea8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/860a1d8e8626a30e511098b703b61ea8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Bill Dubuque](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/197/bill-dubuque) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511892#4511892):**  True, but with things like easily located (polite!) standard meta comments, these folks can help to teach questioners how to pose better questions

**[chessmath http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8d4b364f032ec5fb17c157bd5df47247?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8d4b364f032ec5fb17c157bd5df47247?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [chessmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32609/chessmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511854#4511854):** About downvotes I don't like them at all! Normally this stick cannot be used by new users unless they are mortarboards! But the in the question should be explicit that he wants only a hint!

**[mixedmath http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1066fe6e02bf9b9a52aef4c9b3f8457d?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1066fe6e02bf9b9a52aef4c9b3f8457d?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511857#4511857):**  I do not think if I were to become a moderator tomorrow, my voice or opinion would be any more important than it was yesterday. What I mean is that having a new pair of moderators should not suddenly create a homework policy. In all likelihood, there will be the same sort of differing viewpoint about homework tomorrow as there is today.

**[mixedmath http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1066fe6e02bf9b9a52aef4c9b3f8457d?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1066fe6e02bf9b9a52aef4c9b3f8457d?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511877#4511877):** ... However, to say how I feel about it: I think that what's most important is that we respect each other. Thus if someone carefully crafts an answer that guides the user to the answer, I would consider it impolite for another user to later craft a complete answer. But were someone to flag it - I would not delete it. I might comment - but deletion is too far.

**[robjohn http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6089b0e9c9c12e6fa7ca556f3c860b66?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6089b0e9c9c12e6fa7ca556f3c860b66?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [robjohn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512208#4512208):**  Homework is part of what goes on here. I think that hints should first be given to help provoke thought. If they show interest in working the problem, then more of the answer can be shown in an answer. After a time, say a week or so (to give the assignment to be due), a complete answer could be given for completeness of the site.

**[Gigili http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cf4d8d67ef2dbe02a528fed9ab5360f8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cf4d8d67ef2dbe02a528fed9ab5360f8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513144#4513144):**  I can't relate it to being a moderator. As it is, I'm against posting complete answer for homework in my current position. I think when someone doesn't bother thinking how to provide hints instead of full answer, it's something to think about. But  I didn't find a policy or such s thing on homework questions.

**[Gigili http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cf4d8d67ef2dbe02a528fed9ab5360f8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cf4d8d67ef2dbe02a528fed9ab5360f8?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513145#4513145):** I plan to bring some issue to meta on first days after being elected. It seems to me this is the community where people care a lot about how to react to an special case, so one has to be more careful.

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: Eric Gregor] [Eric Gregor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/33561/eric-gregor) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511771#4511771):* Is it possible that moderation might interfere with your day to day activities? Your own math, for example?

---

**[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511783#4511783):**  I honestly hope it will not. I am a freshman in college, so the demand is not very extreme. I can personally cope with my academic duties, so I feel no problem will arise.

**[image: chessmath] [chessmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32609/chessmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511804#4511804):**  It certainly will not interfere in  my affairs, my fb activities will interfere more!

**[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4511874#4511874):**  Is it possible that moderating might interfere with my math research? It is possible. I am finishing my first year of grad school, and I'm just now beginning to consider my own research. I'm uncertain of how much of a time drain that will be. But I'd be surprised if it took more time than I spent this year - I feel that I did an inordinate amount of math in the last year. So I think my last year of participation is a good indicator of what my future level of participation will be

**[image: robjohn] [robjohn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512162#4512162):**  there is always the chance of interference with a day to day activity. However, that is why there are multiple moderators; others can pick up the  slack, and then I can pick up when they have other responsibilities.

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513172#4513172):**  Currently, I'm in a step in real life that I don't have something like "my own math". But yes, it would if I had. I need to learn more before starting to study masters. I'd say you must pay for what you learn.

Comment: mixedmath's second answer belongs to the homework question.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Fixed now!

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: Antonio Vargas] [Antonio Vargas](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32991/antonio-vargas) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512011#4512011):* Candidates, what authority (moral or otherwise) does/should a moderator have over other users?

---

- **[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [asked for clarification](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512022#4512022):**  I'm sorry - what do you mean about moral authority over other users?

  **[image: Antonio Vargas] [Antonio Vargas](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32991/antonio-vargas) [clarified](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512033#4512033):**  Does a mod have the authority to say what is "the right thing to do"?

**[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512043#4512043):**  I think mods only really have the authority to identify what the 'wrong things to do' are - in the sense that only bad behavior should be 'moderated.' However, in meta discussions and other forms of communication, mods should try to guide the community to behave properly. But decisions as to what is and isn't proper should be community wide, not moderator-thin

- **[image: Antonio Vargas] [Antonio Vargas](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32991/antonio-vargas) [asked for clarification](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512099#4512099):**  Thank you.  Could you clarify what you mean by "mods should try to guide the community to behave properly"?

  **[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [clarified](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512166#4512166):**  By "mods should try to guide the community" I mean that there are many times, such as when new users first post, that someone should try and tell them how things are usually done here. Formatting issues, refraining from the use of imperative, NO ALL CAPS, etc. In responding to these in a good way, mods can set a good example for others.

  **[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512175#4512175):** I notice that Zev responds very well to first time users, for example. And I'd like to emulate that aspect of his moderation style.

**[image: robjohn] [robjohn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512078#4512078):**  I think that moderators should, to a degree, try to lead by example, I have tried to behave to others here in a decent manner.

**[image: robjohn] [robjohn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512102#4512102):**  as for authority, don't like to hold authority over others unless really needed (harassment, etc)

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513360#4513360):**  I don't think so. I read somewhere that moderators are human exception handlers. That is, the difference between them and other users is handling difficult situations where a normal user simply doesn't care and act as "what pleases me" but the moderator needs to act like "what's the best for the benefit of the community".

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513362#4513362):** So no, they don't have the authority, the fact that they're more experience than others to talk about the rules and what's the right thing according to the site policies is something else.

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: Thomas Klimpel] [Thomas Klimpel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/17661/thomas-klimpel) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512231#4512231) [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath):*  The requirements for questions at philosophy.se are much higher than at math.se. Do you think that this simply mirrors the different communities of philosophers and mathematicians, or do you think that the standards for questions should be more comparable?

---

**[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512315#4512315):**  It's true that the requirements for a question at PSE are very high. I think it has a lot to do with the fact that PSE is still working to find itself. MSE had a turbulent beginning as well, and there is still some evidence of this on the meta. But I think that as time goes on, and as PSE grows, the user base will develop a greater consensus on what questions should be around. That was very observant of you, and a good question.

**[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512318#4512318):** ... One thing that does surprise me here is that although many people comment when questions are direct copies of book problems here, such question statements sometimes receive many upvotes. It is not clear to me that such questions "show clear research effort"

- **[image: robjohn] [robjohn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn) [remarked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512331#4512331):**  There should probably be more policing vs plagiarism. Copying book problems without credit is plagiarism.

  **[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [asked for clarification](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512358#4512358):**  Do you mean OPs that copy a problem verbatim?

  **[image: robjohn] [robjohn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn) [clarified](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512362#4512362):**  Yes. restating a problem in their own way with some added thought is fine. But attribution should be given where possible.

  **[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512369#4512369) to [robjohn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/20249/robjohn):**  I agree with you. On many things, in fact. I think you would make a great mod.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Rebecca Chernoff] [Rebecca Chernoff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/23/rebecca-chernoff) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512324#4512324):* **Final thoughts from the candidates please?**

---

**[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512340#4512340):**  I think I said what I had to say, and if anything is missing, I'll try and address the concern the next time I can.

**[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512357#4512357):** I'd like to thank everyone for coming by and asking questions. I think that I can summarize the idea behind most of my answers very simply: I think a moderator should lead by example. Refrain from unilateral action whenever possible. Mods are not the voice of the community, but simply a single voice.

**[image: chessmath] [chessmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32609/chessmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512372#4512372):** Well MSE is an opportunity to learn and teach mathematics around. It also a way to diffuse maths, but we have to keep in mind that are many different levels knowledge in all  Sciences! So be friendlier and that will be an amazing community, better  a brotherhood .

**[image: Bill Dubuque] [Bill Dubuque](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/197/bill-dubuque) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512416#4512416):** Thanks to everyone for joining us. I'm happy to continue elsewhere.

**[image: Gigili] [Gigili](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12356/gigili) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4514039#4514039):** Okay okay, now I'm really done with answering! Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I don't think that chessmath's message was in direct response to the request for final thoughts, but since I was unable to work it in elsewhere I opted to include it here.

Comment: Thanks for your work on this, Tim

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512053#4512053):*  This is a question from a student to users that **are either teaching** or had a **teaching career**. How do you feel in the atmosphere of math.SE? Is it sometimes immature or impersonal? Has anything made you reconsider your participation on the site?

---

**[image: chessmath] [chessmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32609/chessmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512070#4512070):**  yes, yes, yes. But the problem is not the players but the game here.

- **[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [asked for clarification](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512072#4512072):**  I can't get anything from that comment. What do you mean?

  **[image: chessmath] [chessmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32609/chessmath) [clarified](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512093#4512093):**  The system encourages a competitive ambiance here instead of cooperating environment !

  **[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512109#4512109):**  How so? I can recall more cooperative users than competitive. What I do see is criticism to answers/questions, which is natural in a scientific atmosphere.

  **[image: Alex Becker] [Alex Becker](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/10440/alex-becker) [suggested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512128#4512128):**  I think chessmath may be referring to the "race for reputation" that some users have perceived others engaging in.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Marvis] [Marvis](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/911/marvis) [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512068#4512068):*  To attract good teachers and experts, the overall standard of the site must improve, which in-turn means that quality of the questions posed should improve and homework question be discouraged. Do you believe that questions should filtered more and questions that are too elementary must be discouraged? Your thoughts?

---

**[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512115#4512115):**  On the one hand, I believe that questions should be asked in the place where it will receive the best answer. To that end, I see two major players in the math community: MO and MSE. I would be very, very reluctant to preventing any question from being asked here for being too basic. I don't really want to exclude anyone. Whether or not this will eventually lead to a degradation of the average question is unclear to me at the moment. If so, then perhaps change will be necessary.

**[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [continued](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512146#4512146):**  On the other hand, I am uncertain about how to actually attract more experts to the site. To be honest, many of of our experts are here almost exclusively answering questions rather than asking many, and I think it takes a special sort of person to do this. As long as there are questions of interest, I suppose they will stay. But attracting more? I'm very uncertain.

**[image: mixedmath] [mixedmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/13344/mixedmath) [concluded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512117#4512117):** But I don't see that problem yet.

**[image: chessmath] [chessmath](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/32609/chessmath) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512127#4512127):**  Never discourage homework, maths is maths. If we had not homework the   reason of the site would be less effective.

**[image: Peter Tamaroff] [Peter Tamaroff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/30951/peter-tamaroff) [answered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4512148#4512148):**  By no means. Maths should be encouraged at any level. And most people dealing with basic arithmetic or geometry, I think, will not really choose this site to ask. The cases are very few and the answers are simple.