# How do I contribute to the site?

Tags: discussion, support

Check my profile and you will know all I have done on this site in the past 2-3 months is ask some questions. I want to answer some questions and be of use on this site(where a lot of easy questions must be piling up everyday). I have completed high school and I am about to join a college. I thought that there must be some questions out there that I can answer. But, guess what? Either they are already answered or it's way above my level. I tried to find some tags I might be of use with. But in the huge myriad of tags, I couldn't find any. Can anybody suggest ways I can be of use here? coz I really want to be.

Note: I am good at math, at least according to my friends and teachers(if that is relevant).

Comment: Probably not exactly the same question, but these past discussions seem to be at least related: [Is it annoying that I don't answer questions and just ask?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6412), [How can non-experts best contribute?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2085).

Comment: One part of your questions seems to be how to find unanswered questions. If you choose any tag, for example ([tag:algebra-precalculus]), you can click on *unanswered* to get to [unanswered tab for that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus?sort=unanswered). (And you can then change back to active/newest or whichever tab you prefer.)

Comment: @Martin Sleziak Will you please make a list of tags like that for me and others who might have lost their way. If u write an answer with that, I will accept it

Comment: I'm sort of in a similar situation, still in high school and some questions are either over my head or answered quickly by a seasoned mathematician. There are still ways to participate, however. If you have enough rep you can edit questions to add mathjax or clean up the formatting. This is a big help. If you'd like to answer more questions, it might take some time, but keep reading thru them and perhaps you'll learn more from them. In addition, keep asking questions on things you don't understand. This is actually edifying behavior and does contribute positively.

Comment: :P I see a few new answers from you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I looked at your profile and found

- 0 posts edited
- 0 helpful flags
- 4 votes cast

  You can help this site by voting, editing and improving posts (+2 for your reputation), and, if it makes sense, flagging answers, posts and comments. The query uses a parameter Tag that you have to supply. You can enter % so that there all Tags are allowed.

And again, vote!

---

I tinkered around with *StackExchange Data Explorer* and created a query that searches for posts that don't have any answer and where the text of the question or the 'AbouMe' text of the user contains the word 'highschool'. Maybe this is useful to you.

https://data.stackexchange.com/math/revision/685092/854111/unanswered-queries

Comment: ok, ill try. But can u also guide me toward some of the tags where I might be able to answer

Comment: @Truth-seek I added a query to my post.

Comment: your query has been extremely useful, thank you

Answer (score 9):

Dando18 [alluded to this briefly in a comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26508/how-do-i-contribute-to-the-site#comment104830_26508) but I think this is worth emphasizing in a separate answer since no one else appears to have mentioned it.

I look at your profile and I see 10 questions, 9 of which have accepted answers.  The few questions I looked at in detail are clear and well formed.  **Asking such questions and accepting answers is one way to contribute positively to this site.**  Based on your question here it sounds like you don't think you're contributing, but you already are.  This is a Q&A site, and without Qs we just have As.  [And an A without a Q is just a statement.](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8N_pDtLo1Bk/maxresdefault.jpg)

More seriously, as you progress through college you'll find that you'll be able to answer more questions on this site (if you continue to take math courses), but you'll likely find that you'll have less time to do so, anyway.

Finally, the vast majority of schools in the US are on summer break right now.  The traffic will pick up when classes resume in the fall.  I don't know the breakdown of traffic to this site by country but I imagine a very large chunk of it comes from the US.

Comment: Thnx for telling me I am useful to the site

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [most popular tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags) I can suggest:

- [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) *
- [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) *
- [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus)
- [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) *
- [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)
- [elementary-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-number-theory) *
- [functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions)
- [trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry)

Where a * means that some of the problems in that tag that are above your level. That's not to say that the ones without a * will not contain problems you can't answer (indeed it would be impressive if you could answer all the questions in any tag) but just that the * ones are meant for problems at several levels and some of those are going to be beyond you at this time.